# Nginx Nextcloud too many redirects

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt, cloudflare, nextcloud

I am trying to install Nextcloud on my Raspberry Pi.

1. I have created an `A record` in Cloudflare with subdomain pointing to my Raspberry Pi IP address and configured the `NGINX` with `certbot` using the default configuration file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/nextcloud`.

   2. I have created symlink in `/etc/nginx/sites-enables` and checked the `NGINX` configuration with `sudo nginx -t` and the configuration was all valid.
   3. I am getting successfully redirected to `https` but I am getting an error that I am getting too many redirects when I try to open the `nextcloud.mydomain.com` in a browser.

This is my `nextcloud` config:

```
upstream php-handler {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #server unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name nextcloud.domain.com;

    if ($host = nextcloud.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$server_name:443$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nextcloud.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nextcloud.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nextcloud.domain.com/chain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot

    # Add headers to serve security related headers
    # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into this
    # topic first.
    #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
    #
    # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
    # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
    # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
    # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
    # could take several months.
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
    add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
    add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
    add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;

    # Remove X-Powered-By, which is an information leak
    fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;

    # Path to the root of your installation
    root /var/www/html/nextcloud;

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # The following 2 rules are only needed for the user_webfinger app.
    # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
    #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
    #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

    # The following rule is only needed for the Social app.
    # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
    #rewrite ^/.well-known/webfinger /public.php?service=webfinger last;

    location = /.well-known/carddav {
      return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
    }
    location = /.well-known/caldav {
      return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
    }

    # set max upload size
    client_max_body_size 512M;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    # Enable gzip but do not remove ETag headers
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
    gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/bmp image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/cache-manifest text/css text/plain text/vcard text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;

    # Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
    # This module is currently not supported.
    #pagespeed off;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ ^\/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)\/ {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ ^\/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^\/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core\/ajax\/update|status|ocs\/v[12]|updater\/.+|oc[ms]-provider\/.+)\.php(?:$|\/) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(\/.*|)$;
        set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        # Avoid sending the security headers twice
        fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;
        # Enable pretty urls
        fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
        fastcgi_pass php-handler;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_request_buffering off;
    }

    location ~ ^\/(?:updater|oc[ms]-provider)(?:$|\/) {
        try_files $uri/ =404;
        index index.php;
    }

    # Adding the cache control header for js, css and map files
    # Make sure it is BELOW the PHP block
    location ~ \.(?:css|js|woff2?|svg|gif|map)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=15778463";
        # Add headers to serve security related headers (It is intended to
        # have those duplicated to the ones above)
        # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into
        # this topic first.
        #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
        #
        # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
        # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
        # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
        # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
        # could take several months.
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
        add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
        add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
        add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;

        # Optional: Don't log access to assets
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \.(?:png|html|ttf|ico|jpg|jpeg|bcmap)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
        # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

This is the curl output:

```
curl -i http://nextcloud.domain.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 03 Feb 2020 20:54:01 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Expires: Mon, 03 Feb 2020 21:54:01 GMT
Location: https://nextcloud.domain.com/
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 55f74c364a04d8d1-AMS
```

And when I try to access the `https` version:

```
curl -i https://nextcloud.domain.com 

HTTP/2 301 
date: Mon, 03 Feb 2020 20:55:45 GMT
content-type: text/html
set-cookie: __cfduid=d160f56e9986d2c7037ff81e233fcad0e1580763345; expires=Wed, 04-Mar-20 20:55:45 GMT; path=/; domain=.domain.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
location: https://nextcloud.domain.com:443/
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-robots-tag: none
x-download-options: noopen
x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
referrer-policy: no-referrer
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 55f74ebf5ed62bfe-AMS

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I have replaced my domain name with `domain`.

In the `/var/log/nginx/access.log` I am getting a lot of lines with the redirect and HTTP codes: 301 and 185.

If I delete the redirect `return 301 https://$server_name:443@request_uri;` line I am still getting redirected to `https` and I don't have any idea why.

For the record, I used to have `lighttpd` in the past installed on the Raspberry Pi but I have uninstalled it before installing the `NGINX`.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46413494/err-too-many-redirects-with-nginx/60789055#60789055

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a single `server` definition for both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` and, as you noticed, the lines:

```
if ($host = nextcloud.domain.com) {
    return 301 https://$server_name:443$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
```

are doing most of the damage. Since it is a `301` redirect, you browser will remember it until it is restarted.

Split the configuration of the two listening ports, so that the first lines are:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name nextcloud.domain.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name nextcloud.domain.com;
    # rest of the config
```

**Edit**: As you remarked, you can put both `listen` directives in one `server` block, however this will cause a **redirect loop** if your server is accessed directly using the `nextcloud.domain.com`. Cloudflare probably puts another proxy server between your clients and **nginx** and forwards requests using your IP instead of the domain name. So the loop remains hidden, but is is still there.

If you want to keep the single server block, you should consider changing the `if` condition to:

```
if ($scheme = http) {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
```

However, in terms of clarity and performance, it is probably worse than two `server` blocks.

Comment: actually, I have just fixed my issue and it was related to the Cloudflare DNS configuration. There I have enabled re-write HTTP to HTTPS and this caused the problem. Additionally, I have enabled the DNS to be proxied. Since I fixed it I am not experiencing any more redirects. Plus listening on both ports in the same server block is also OK according to the official `NGINX` documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server . If I check the output with curl I am seeing one 301 redirect HTTP->HTTPS and then 302 to the login page and 200 for login

Comment: You can't configure a `HTTP` redirect with `DNS` so Cloudflare probably points your domain to their servers, which act as a reverse proxy. Is `cloudflare.domain.com` pointing to your IP? If that were the case your configuration would cause a redirect loop. I edited the answer with more details.

Comment: This is exactly what happened, yes, they were proxying the requests to my domain through their IPs